# Selenium Python getting <script> tag information?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take information inside the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> INFO </script>
```

More specifically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="js logged-in client-root">
<head>...</head>
<body class style ="position: fixed; top: -265px; width: 100%;">
  <span id="react-root" aria-hidden="true">...</span>
  <script type="text/javascript> This is the tag i want. </script>
  <script type="text/javascript> 
     window.__initialDataLoaded(window._sharedData); </script>
...
```

I am trying this but no luck:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
info = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']")
print(info.text) //prints nothing
```

Comment: can you post the URL of the website that you are trying or the HTML code?

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the `outerHTML`

Comment: https://instagram.com I am trying to extract comment times which are in <script> tag

Comment: @DebanjanB I didn't understand what you mean...

Comment: @doruksahin Update the HTML with more of its _preceding_ and _following_ tags

Comment: @DebanjanB done.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? and I think it's in frame , please check whether it's in iframe or not and update us

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like this is the expected behavior. See [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3033#issuecomment-191978779):

> This is working correctly.  `WebElement#getText` returns the *visible* text that a user
>   can see.  The user cannot see text in a `<script>` tag, so it is not returned by `getText`.
>   You can still access contents of the tag through JavaScript

So you will have to do something like this:

```
info.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, I get page source and inspector from my browser. When i compare them something is different. Page source has commented time information but inspecting won't help me.

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate more on what you mean by "commented time information"?

Comment: I am scraping instagram. When im using Chrome manually, checked "Page source" and "Inspect element". I compared them and they wasnt the same. driver.page_source gave me "Inspect element" info, not "Page source". Is there a way i can scrap "Page source" with selenium?

Comment: If you want page source, then a scraper might be a better option. Try looking at BeautifulSoup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)